# Asyncio issue with Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

Running a simple python script with an async function gives this error in any subsequent `print()` statements: `OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid` on Windows using python 3.11.6. The code works fine on Linux and MacOS though.

Full code:

```
import ezkl
import asyncio

async def f():
    res = await ezkl.calibrate_settings("input.json", "model_4.onnx", "settings.json", "resources")

asyncio.run(f())

print("test")
```

Tried using `nest_asyncio.apply()` and also the below modified code but without any luck - still receive the same `OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid` error.

```
import ezkl
import asyncio

async def f():
    res = await ezkl.calibrate_settings("input.json", "model_4.onnx", "settings.json","resources")

nest_asyncio.apply()
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(f())

print("test")
```

Comment: this is more likely a bug in the ezkl project.

Comment: nopes, even after making ezkl's async function a sync function still giving the same error on `print()` statement